# How to retrieve records from to columns into a single column in order?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing two columns. I need to retrieve the contents of two columns into one single column in order using Oracle query.

```
FirstName      LastName
Naveen         Bharadwaj
Usain          Bolt
```

I want to retrieve records into a single column such that the first name and last name are in order.

```
Name
Naveen
Bharadwaj
Usain
Bolt
```

P.S: I cannot use decode() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query for desired result,

```
SELECT Name FROM TableName UNPIVOT (Name FOR NAME IN (FirstName,LastName));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To get the records into a single column, you can use [the UNION ALL operator](http://www.databasestar.com/union-vs-union-all).

If you want them to remain in the order that they are in the table, you can order by the ID or primary key column. I assume that you have one because you need to know what the original order is, in order to keep it.

So, something like this:

```
SELECT fullname
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS name_type,
    name_id,
    firstname AS fullname
    FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    2,
    name_id,
    lastname
    FROM yourtable
) sub
ORDER BY sub.name_id, sub.name_type;
```

The name_type indicates 1 for a first name and 2 for a last name, which is used for ordering and to keep the first name on top of the last name.
The subquery is used because you only want to display the name, but order by other columns.

I would suggest using UNION ALL instead of UNION because there may be duplicates you want to keep, and therefore the performance may be better.

Comment: I'm sorry I had typed the question in mobile and there was a formatting problem. The output that I desire is as edited in the question. First name and last name as new rows.

Comment: Thank you. But the query is returning results in wrong order. The order is "Naveen, Usain, Bharadwaj, Bolt"
Expected is:
"Naveen, Bharadwaj, Usain, Bolt"

Comment: Also, I dont have any ID (name_id) here